# Receive POST message body in VIsualforce controller

Tags: visualforce, controller, integration, post

I realise that I can receive parameters in the query string via the following syntax:

```
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('parameterName');
```

This also seems to work for parameters encoded in a query string format inside the message body of a POST request.

However, my use case involves a public sites page that needs to receive / parse a JSON string in the message body of the post request. This message body content is set in stone, as it's being sent from a server that's outside my control (and outside of SF) - I can only provide the URL to send it to.

Is there any way to obtain this data, or if not any other possible workaround from within SF?

Comment: Not clear about your question is the service is hosted at SF side? if so there is a getBody() method to extract the body from a POST request see here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_httprequest.htm
and if you want to consume the service we have setBody() method

Comment: @AvijitChakraborty Afraid not, the service is hosted on an external server that has nothing to do with SF.

Comment: If you need to get a JSON that is being posted to Salesforce from another service, have you considered publishing a public REST endpoint using your site?

Comment: @RenatoOliveira Ahah - I hadn't, but that may well be the answer here!

Comment: An [Apex REST Webservice](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest.htm) ([Apex REST Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest_methods.htm) is probably the specific page you're looking for) is the answer to your question here. I'll let @RenatoOliveira take the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to parse a JSON that is being posted by an external service, you'll probably want to build a public REST endpoint in your organisation using your public Site.

You can find more about this on the Apex Developer Guide, on sections "[Exposing Apex Classes as REST Web Services](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest.htm)" and "[Apex REST Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest_methods.htm)".

There are [videos on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A-nzywBLUbM) showing how to do this as well.

Comment: Thanks very much, I wasn't aware of the REST endpoint functionality in Salesforce, but that fits the bill perfectly.